# List<IPAddress> to PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am getting a list of `IPAddress` and now i want to show them in the [`PropertyGrid` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

for example:

```
IP Address
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
.
.
.
```

is that possible somehow ?
ive tried it with

```
propertygrid.SelectedObject = ipAddresses //ipAddresses is the list of the IP´s
```

can someone help me maybe ?

Comment: Consider to use GridView instead of PropertyGrid

Comment: I think you would first need to populate your list before trying anything such as selecting a value , else expect some crashes

Comment: well ive got an IPAddress Model from the .net framework ... how can i get out the value of the ip .. in the model theres only the long address ---